# Use like operator in Crystal Report record selection formula

Tags: crystal-reports, sql-like

Hi I am using Crystal Report 2008 to create a report. I need to convert the following oracle SQL query to Crystal Report record selection formula.

Oracle Query is :

```
AND 
(
  UPPER(920_SEARCH_REPORT.HANDICAP_TYPE) LIKE UPPER(:HANDICAP_TYPE)
  OR UPPER(920_SEARCH_REPORT.SKSKODENR) LIKE UPPER(:SKSKODENR)
)
```

I have convert this to formula like following way :

```
and 
(
    isnull({?Hancicap_Type}) = true 
        or ((UpperCase({?Hancicap_Type}) Like ("*"&UpperCase({920_SEARCH_REPORT.HANDICAP_TYPE})&"*"))    
        or (UpperCase({?SKSKODENR}) Like ("*"&UpperCase({920_SEARCH_REPORT.SKSKODENR})&"*")))
)
```

But data is not showing when crystal report executes. But the sql query returns one record.

Can anyone help me to solve the problem.

Comment: What is the use of isnull in formula

Comment: It checks whether the parameter value is null or not. IsNull function is not necessary to use. we can do like this way:        {?Hancicap_Type} = "" Or ....

Comment: That is the point you are missing.... im this case use if function then i am sure your formula will work

Comment: can you give a idea. a sample code. it will help me. my other condition is working nicely where multiple or operator is not used.

Comment: I had the same general problem, but I was using normal SQL syntax (%) instead of Crystal syntax (*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the proper syntax for parameters: `{?parameter_name}`.

```
...
AND 
(
  ( UPPER(920_SEARCH_REPORT.HANDICAP_TYPE) LIKE "*" + UPPERCASE({?HANDICAP_TYPE}) + "*")
  OR 
  ( UPPER(920_SEARCH_REPORT.SKSKODENR) LIKE "*" + UPPERCASE({?SKSKODENR}) + "*")
)
```